# Problem Changing Column Order in a Table (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, ddl

When I try to change this columns list:

```
Nombre
Imagen
Descripcion
Activo
IdLineaProducto
```

into this (IdLineaProducto is first)

```
IdLineaProducto
Nombre
Imagen
Descripcion
Activo
```

SQL Server Management Studio says that it's not allowed to save changes because the table must be deleted and recreated (in spanish...). I could do this in SQL Server 2005, but not in SQL Server 2008.

The same happens in other situations, like trying to transform an int non-identity column to identity. Why happens this? How can I resolve this? Maybe some misconfigured issue? Some new feature in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the [solution to this problem](http://pragmaticworks.com/community/blogs/brianknight/archive/2008/06/04/sql-server-2008-designer-behavior-change-saving-changes-not-permitted.aspx).

> This is by design and can be quickly
>   fixed in Management Studio by
>   unchecking a property. To fix this in
>   Management Studio, go to Tools ->
>   Options then go to the Designer Page
>   and uncheck "Prevent saving changes
>   that require table re-creation".

Beware that it may have [undesired consequences](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2009/01/23/management-studio-got-smarter.aspx), like losing data in other tables related to this.

Comment: Accept you answer. Looks like you answered you own question. I wondered why that was not possible SQL2008 as it was previous versions. +1

Answer (score 1):

That is just the way it works... you can only add columns to the end, unless you `DROP` it and `CREATE` it (normally copying the data out and back in, which the IDE might help with). But *why* do you want to change the order? Even if it isn't ideal, your `SELECT` etc can handle this... i.e.

```
SELECT IdLineaProducto, Nombre, Imagen, Descripcion, Activo
FROM   TheTable
...
```

(it is rarely a good idea to just use `SELECT *`)

---

Re the `IDENTITY`; again, this is fundamental to the column - although in this case you could copy the data out, `DROP` the column, and re-`ADD` the column as `IDENTITY` (on the right hand side), and copy it back in - but then you have extra complications with `IDENTITY INSERT` and the `SEED` value (so you don't try to get duplicates of existing identity values).

Comment: Well, yes, you are right. But I used to see database columns in certain logical order, specially when tables has many columns. Also, I'm talking about working with the designer, not TSQL code. When I work with the designer I get these messages.